# Unable to connect to Cannon LIDE 400 Scanner On Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, scanner, canon

On my freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 where I imported user's home from my previous installation, I have an annoying issue with my Canon CanoScan LIDE 400. The printer is detected by Ubuntu:

[image: screenshot showing that the printer is detected by Ubuntu]

However it cannot scan. Instead, it gives this error when I click *Scan* on Simple Scanner:

> **Failed to scan**
> Unable to connect to scanner

[image: Failed to scan error]

I had the same scanner working on the same machine before, after lots and lots of googling and fiddling, but now I have no clue how to get it to work.

I have installed the driver from the [official Cannon drivers](https://www.canon.pt/support/consumer_products/products/scanners/lide_series/canoscan-lide-400.html?type=drivers&language=&os=linux). It gives this file `scangearmp2-3.70-1-deb.tar.gz` which I extracted and then run the `install.sh`:

```
me@pc:~/Downloads/scangearmp2-3.70-1-deb$ sudo bash install.sh 
==================================================

ScanGear MP
Version 3.70
Copyright CANON INC. 2007-2018

==================================================
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/scangearmp2_3.70-1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 205144 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../scangearmp2_3.70-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking scangearmp2 (3.70-1) over (3.70-1) ...
Setting up scangearmp2 (3.70-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Installation has been completed.
```

I have also restarted the OS and changed the USB port, but to no avail.

I appreciate your hints to solve this and save me from throwing the scanner out of the window.